# Mongoose schema doesn't exports to the routes

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I would like to export my schema to the file where I have routes, but it keeps giving me an error that says: (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname), which I don't understand.

I have already tried a different way of how to export schema such as:

```
module.exports = Albi = mongoose.model('albi', AlbiSchema);
```

but since I have more than one schema in the file, it kept rerouting me to another schema.

right now I'm using this code, but it gives me the weird error

```
export const Albi = mongoose.model('Albi', AlbiSchema);
```

The outcome that I would like to have from this is to be able to export the schema, so I can use this kind of route in my route file:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    Albi.find({})
        .populate('category')
        .populate('area')
        .exec()
            .then(albi =>res.json(albi))
            .catch(err => res.send(err))
});
```

thank you for all the tips!

Comment: When you say that you have more than one schema in the file and it kept rerouting you to another schema you mean that using require(this_file) returns the last exported schema in the file, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can export like this for single schema as a default one.

```
const Albi = mongoose.model("Albi", AlbiSchema);
export default Albi;
```

and can import as

```
import Albi from "pathToSchemaFile"
```

To export multiple schemas, define like this

```
module.exports = {Albi, Second, Third }
```

And import it as

```
const schemas = require("./pathToSchemaFile");
schemas.Albi.find({});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.
1.first.
var Albi= module.exports = mongoose.model('Albi', AlbiSchema);
2.second
var schema=require('./schema file path here.');
3.Third
 schemas.find({});